# Routing a modular app with Ampersand.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, modular, ampersand.js

I am trying to write my first modular app using Ampersand.js but I'm having a few issues! Hoping somebody can point me in the right direction...

Ok so I have configured `Watchify` and `Browserify` into my html file to create a `bundled.js` file that will be recompiled every time I make a change. I then wanted to add an Ampersand module- `ampersand-router` (installed in terminal as `npm install --save ampersand-router` to specify all of the application routes I'd like to handle and redirect users if they hit an unavailable route.

The problem its not redirecting my # routes and I cant figure out why! Because I don't have a server (or need one for this project) I am trying to use # based routing and i'd like it to handle three routes, an empty route (my starting point), `gif/id` route an a `catch` route which will redirect to the starting point.

So my file structure contains a router.js:-

```
'use strict';
var AmpersandRouter = require('ampersand-router');
module.exports = AmpersandRouter.extend({
routes:{
    '': 'gifs', //empty
    'gif/:id': 'gif',
    'catch': 'catch' //catch and redirect
},
gifs: function(){
    console.log('gifs page');
},

gif: function(id){
    console.log('gif page', id);
},
'catch': function(){
    this.redirectTo('');
}
```

});

and a app.js file:-

```
var Router = require('./router.js');
window.app = {
init: function () {
    console.log('hello world');
    this.router = new Router();
    this.router.history.start();
}
};
window.app.init();
```

and this is all assembled `<script src = "bundled.js"></script>` in my index.html and package.json code below

```
"scripts": {
"start": "watchify js/app.js -o bundled.js",
"build": "browserify js/app.js -o bundled.js"
```

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

What happens? Any errors? Also, you might try jumping into the project chat and asking in there: https://gitter.im/AmpersandJS/AmpersandJS

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling `pushState`

```
this.router.history.start({pushState: false});
```

When it is enabled the #-fallback won't kick in.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried to use 'npm start' in your base directory?

I haven't put Ampersand.js into an HTML file, but it seems to work with pure Javascript.